# Unwanted underline display under hyperlinks

Tags: css

I am trying to display line when mouse hover on links and that works fine, but another white line appeared when hover on links

CSS:

```
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:focus 
 {
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
  border-bottom: solid 3px red;
 }
```

[image]

How to remove the white line under Home link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code:

```
  text-decoration: underline;
```

to

```
  text-decoration: none;
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the `text-decoration: underline;` to `text-decoration: none;` on your CSS code. Use the following code:

```
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: white;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: due to James answered first, so I will mark his answer but I will up-vote your answer as well. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: OK, but what's the difference between my or @James answer?

Comment: Both james and i is right. (did not see his answer when i post)